# WPML same slug(url) different language

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I have this site :

example.com/watches (watches is a custom post type)

There are two available languages : EN(default language), GR.

When i change to GR (while on **page example.com/watches**)
 it redirects to **example.com/el/watches** which is right.

When i am on **example.com/watches/rolex** and i try to change language it redirects to **example.com/el/taxwatches/rolex-el** but i want it just to be **example.com/el/watches/rolex/**.

**taxwatches** is my custom taxonomy.

**rolex-el** is the slug of the term inside that taxonomy.

Has anyone experienced an issue like this before?

I've tried to save the permalinks again and check my WMPL settings but i can't see something wrong.

EDIT 1 : If i manually go to **example.com/el/watches/rolex** it will work fine. 
Both **example.com/el/watches/rolex** and **example.com/el/taxwatches/rolex-el** work.

EDIT 2: From what i understand WPML takes the slugs, is there a way to change it so it takes the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so for anyone having problems with multi language sites - but want to have the "same slugs" in the urls (will never be same slugs - but going to look like that) read the below.

WPML uses slugs which are created from the wordpress core structure - you can't have two slugs with the exactly same name. If default language is EN and you have a secondary, in my case GR, then one slug is going to be "myslug" and the other "myslug-gr" (you can customize this "-gr" through WPML settings).

In **functions.php** you can filter the "**wpml_ls_filter**" function which is fired when your Language switcher is created.

Code as below :

```
add_filter('icl_ls_languages', 'wpml_ls_filter');

function wpml_ls_filter($languages) {

   foreach ($languages as $lang_code => $language) {

       $mTempString = $languages[$lang_code]['url'];

       echo $mTempString; // HERE

       // If "tax" is found in that string, replace it with "" - remove it.
       if (strpos($mTempString, "tax") !== false) {

              $languages[$lang_code]['url'] = str_replace("tax", "", $mTempString);
       }

   }
return $languages;
}
```

The above `echo` is going to show you the url that is created (and you can manipulate it) of each language button when pressed whenever you visit a page/post.

I haven't wrote a complete solution because that really depends on what you want to do. For example the above code helped me achieve to remove "**tax**" if found in the url.

Comment: @BGBruno You will have to go to the Wordpress Theme's files > functions.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use my plugin, it is based on the newest Polylang Pro module and does what you need: https://github.com/lufton/polylang-share-slug

Answer (score 0):

This answer is providing an alternative way to achieve **multiple languages with same slug**

Polylang with Polylang Slug these 2 plugins can do

https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

https://github.com/grappler/polylang-slug/